# A topological vector space is separated if and only if $\{0\}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

I am new to the study of topological vector space and I would like to show the result stated in the title above but I have some doubt, hence the question.

For the first implication, I don’t know how use the fact that the topological vector space (TVS) is separated. Since the mapping $f(x)=\lambda x$, $\lambda\neq 0$ is an homeomorphism it seems natural for me to conclude by noting that $f^{-1}(0_{\mathbb{R}})=\{0\}$ is closed as the inverse image of a closed set by a continuous function.

For the second implication, I have no clue on how to proceed. If you have some hint (rather than full answer) I would be glad to read this please.

Do not hesitate to tell me what goes wrong in my first implication also.. thank you a lot !

---

Of course $f$ is not real valued so the first implication is false as noticed by a comment !

Comment: $f$ as you've defined it isn't a map into $\mathbb{R}$, so I don't believe your argument from the inverse image.

Comment: @Chessanator Totally right. Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

See the comments for your idea about the left-to-right implication: $x \mapsto \lambda x$ is not a map from the Hilbert space to $\Bbb{R}$.

As for hints: if $0$ is closed, then for any $v \neq 0$, $0$ has an open neighbourhood $U$ such that $v \not\in U$. What can you say about $U + v = \{ u + v : u \in U\}$? If $0$ is not closed, then there is a $v \neq 0$, such that every neighbourhood of $v$ contains $0$.